# amsart, no upcase in title and shorttitle (smaller fonts for shorttitle)

Tags: titles, fontsize, amsart

please consider

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\let\origmaketitle\maketitle
\def\maketitle{
    \begingroup
    \def\uppercasenonmath##1{} % this disables uppercasing title
    \let\MakeUppercase\relax % this disables uppercasing authors
    \origmaketitle
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\title[Ersrerr'f pbzzragf: Vzcebirq ybpny rkvfgrapr naq
vzcebirq pbagvahngvba pevgrevba]{Ersrerr'f pbzzragf ba gur negvpyr:
  Vzcebirq ybpny rkvfgrapr, havdhrarff naq ybpnyvmrq pbagvahngvba
  pevgrevba sbe fbyhgvbaf gb gur Rhyre--Cbvffba flfgrz jvgu pbzcnpgyl
  fhccbegrq vavgvny qngn} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Some text
\newpage 
more text
\end{document}
```

So the long title is not using uppercases. I would like to have the same for the shorttitle, and in
addition I would also like to have a slightly smaller font for the shorttitle in case it is too long to fit on the header.
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The uppercasing is because there is no `\shortauthors` field and, in this case, `amsart` defines `\shortauthors` the same as `\shorttitle`.

And the class (in its contorted way, as usual) applies `\MakeUppercase` to `\shortauthors` anyway.

Solution: patch `\maketitle` and `\@settitle`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\uppercasenonmath\shorttitle}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}{\the\toks@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@settitle}{\uppercasenonmath\@title}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\title[Ersrerr'f pbzzragf: Vzcebirq ybpny rkvfgrapr naq
  vzcebirq pbagvahngvba pevgrevba]{Ersrerr'f pbzzragf ba gur negvpyr:
  Vzcebirq ybpny rkvfgrapr, havdhrarff naq ybpnyvmrq pbagvahngvba
  pevgrevba sbe fbyhgvbaf gb gur Rhyre--Cbvffba flfgrz jvgu pbzcnpgyl
  fhccbegrq vavgvny qngn}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Some text
\newpage

more text

\end{document}
```

I'd be wary about automatically resizing the short title: it's already typeset at a very small font size.

[image]

If you load `hyperref`, you need to patch the original command, not the version defined by `hyperref`. Code independent on the loading of `hyperref` follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\patchcmd{\HyOrg@maketitle}}{\patchcmd{\maketitle}}%
  {\uppercasenonmath\shorttitle}{}{}{}
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\patchcmd{\HyOrg@maketitle}}{\patchcmd{\maketitle}}%
  {\@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}{\the\toks@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@settitle}{\uppercasenonmath\@title}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\title[Ersrerr'f pbzzragf: Vzcebirq ybpny rkvfgrapr naq
  vzcebirq pbagvahngvba pevgrevba]{Ersrerr'f pbzzragf ba gur negvpyr:
  Vzcebirq ybpny rkvfgrapr, havdhrarff naq ybpnyvmrq pbagvahngvba
  pevgrevba sbe fbyhgvbaf gb gur Rhyre--Cbvffba flfgrz jvgu pbzcnpgyl
  fhccbegrq vavgvny qngn} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Some text
\newpage 

more text

\end{document}
```

Less of a mouthful:

```
\providecommand\patchcs[1]{\expandafter\patchcmd\csname#1\endcsname}

\makeatletter
\patchcs{\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{HyOrg@}{}maketitle}
  {\uppercasenonmath\shorttitle}{}{}{}
\patchcs{\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{HyOrg@}{}maketitle}
  {\@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}{\the\toks@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@settitle}{\uppercasenonmath\@title}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, just to make this clear: to have both title and short title **not** in uppercases I need

    \usepackage{etoolbox}

    \makeatletter

    \patchcmd{\maketitle}{\uppercasenonmath\shorttitle}{}{}{}
    
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}{\the\toks@}{}{}
    
\let\origmaketitle\maketitle
    
\def\maketitle{

     \begingroup

     \def\uppercasenonmath##1{} % this disables uppercasing title
     \let\MakeUppercase\relax % this disables uppercasing authors
     \origmaketitle
     \endgroup
    }
    \makeatother

Comment: @UweBrauer Sorry, I overlooked the requirement for the title. Now I provided a simpler method than yours for the title.

Comment: no sorry, thanks, interesting comment:
if you put
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} 
**before** your definition of the title, 
it seems not to work
very strange

Comment: @UweBrauer Added the code for `hyperref`.

Comment: **Great** thanks so much!